# Escape ampersand in xsl url parameter

Tags: xslt, ampersand

I have an xsl document with javascript int it in which i append url parameters to the string.

```
 window.parent.parent.addTab('Loading...', 'PGS/ContentView.aspx?dpath=' + dpath + '&hashValue=' + hashValue);
```

The xsl using visual studio gives me an error stating entity 'hashvalue' not defined, its a valid parameter being passed to the function.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the ampersand with &amp;?

Comment: @StylesYoung What is the error when you escape the ampersand? Is it the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `&amp;` and wrap it in the xsl:text:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>
```